# Why top input function not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In Area 1, when I checked checkbox bbbbbb or checkbox cccccc
input will disable , it's not work

But in Area 2 it's OK

Why Area1 function not work ?

thank you.

```
Area 1
<br>
<input type="text" id="a" name="a">   
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="b" name="b"/> bbbbbb
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="c" name="c"/> cccccc
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('b').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('c').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('c').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('b').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;

};
}
</script>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Area 2
<br>

<input type="text" id="1" name="1">   
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="2"/> 222222
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="3"/> 333333
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('2').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('3').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('1').disabled = this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('3').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('2').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('1').disabled = this.checked;

};
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The second `window.onload` is overriding the first one.

Answer (score 3):

> Why Area1 function not work ?

Because you are **overwriting** `window.onload` with a new function. Only the function that you assigned *last* will be executed on page load.

That's one of the reasons why to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to bind event handlers:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // ..
});
```

This allows you to bind multiple handlers to the same element.

There are a couple of alternatives:

- Aggregate both functions into one.
- Create the functions explicitly and call both in the event handler. E.g.

  ```
  function area1() { ... }
  function area2() { ... }
  window.onload = function() {
      area1();
      area2();
  };
  ```
- Don't use `window.onload` at all. Since you already placed the code after the elements in the document, you don't need `window.onload`. You can run the code directly, e.g.

  ```
  Area 1
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="a" name="a">   
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="b" name="b"/> bbbbbb
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c" name="c"/> cccccc
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('b').onchange = function () {
      document.getElementById('c').checked = false;
      document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;
  };
  document.getElementById('c').onchange = function () {
      document.getElementById('b').checked = false;
      document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;

  };
  </script>
  ```

---

I recommend to read [the excellent articles about event handling on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html). The explain all the different ways of how to bind event handlers.

Comment: I Change To

`<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
document.getElementById('b').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('c').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('c').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('b').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;

};
}
</script>`


but not work ?

Comment: That's because you didn't close the `addEventListener` function call. You are missing `);` at the end: http://jsfiddle.net/hmL4a/. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820), so that you can find such typographic errors on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the window.onload=function(){ function twice, it can only be declared once. If you declare it twice, it will choose one of them to work when the window is loaded. Use this instead:

```
Area 1
<br>
<input type="text" id="a" name="a">   
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="b" name="b"/> bbbbbb
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="c" name="c"/> cccccc
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Area 2
<br>

<input type="text" id="1" name="1">   
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="2"/> 222222
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="3"/> 333333

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('b').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('c').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('c').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('b').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;

};
document.getElementById('2').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('3').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('1').disabled = this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('3').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('2').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('1').disabled = this.checked;

};
}
</script>
```

Comment: *"If you declare it twice, it will choose one of them to work when the window is loaded."* You make it sound more complicated than it is. One the page is loaded, the browser does something like `window.onload()`. So whatever function is assigned to `window.onload` at that moment will be executed.

Comment: It sounds simple, "if you declare window.onload twice, it will choose one of the to use instead of the other", you can't get any simpler =D, but yea, you can only declare it once on the page, just have all the functions in it.

Comment: Maybe not complicated, but more complex: it sounds like one of the functions would be arbitrarily chosen, which is not the case. The last assigned function before page load will be called on page load.